# Multiple Rows update in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

my SQL table

```
table->requirement

id        label_name      label_value      requirement_id   
103         budget         5000                 4           
104       specialist      dentist               4          
105       treatment       clinic                4          
106       expertise       criminal              5          
107       charges          5100                 5
```

i am trying to update `label_value` in this this table by `mysql-php`.

i have tried this code in php but it is working.

```
foreach ($data as $columnName => $colValue) {
    echo   $subQuery .= "UPDATE `$tableName` SET `label_value`='$colValue' where (`label_name`='$columnName' AND `requirement_id`='$id')";
    mysql_query($subQuery);
    }
```

GETTING OUTPUT-

> UPDATE `requirement` SET `label_value`='Physician' where (`label_name`='specialist' AND `requirement_id`='2')
>
> UPDATE `requirement` SET `label_value`='Physician' where (`label_name`='specialist' AND `requirement_id`='2')
>
> UPDATE `requirement` SET `label_value`='On Your Home' where (`label_name`='Appointment' AND `requirement_id`='2')

I don't know this is correct or not but i need to update this table in form. please help me out of this.

Comment: Well no requirement_id 2 in your table exist!!

Comment: I have checked this requirement_id 2 is available

Comment: And just remove `.` from `.= "UPDATE ` because it concatenate  your query every time

Comment: Oh ok thanks i'll try

Comment: @Saty thank you that is the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106972/discussion-between-gautam-jha-and-saty).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `.` from  `.= "UPDATE` because it will concatenate your query.

For first itration of loop it will generate

```
UPDATE `$tableName` SET `label_value`='$colValue' where (`label_name`='$columnName' AND `requirement_id`='$id'
```

This query works But for second itration it will generate

```
UPDATE `$tableName` SET `label_value`='$colValue' where (`label_name`='$columnName' AND `requirement_id`='$id' UPDATE `$tableName` SET `label_value`='$colValue' where (`label_name`='$columnName' AND `requirement_id`='$id'
```

This is wrong syntax.

Just Use

```
foreach ($data as $columnName => $colValue) {
    echo   $subQuery = "UPDATE `$tableName` SET `label_value`='$colValue' where (`label_name`='$columnName' AND `requirement_id`='$id')";
    mysql_query($subQuery);
    }
```

Try to learn `mysqli or pdo` because mysql is depricated

Also learn [mysqli_multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Comment: i didn't down your vote i just to say a big thanks because you got my problem in no time